# merge all keys of dictionary of dictionary and create new dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

i am having one dictionary

```
{
   "a": "b",
   "c": {
       "d": "e",
       "f": {
           "g": "h",
           "i": "j"
       }
   }
}
```

i want output like:

```
{
   "a": "b",
   "c.d": "e",
   "c.f.g": "h",
   "c.f.i": "j"
}
```

I tried to solve

```
>>> def handle(inp):
    out = {}
    for i in inp:
        if type(inp[i]) is dict:
            for jj in inp[i].keys():
                out[i+'.'+jj] = inp[i][jj]
        else:
            out[i] = inp[i]
    return out

>>> handle(inp)
{'a': 'b', 'c.f': {'i': 'j', 'g': 'h'}, 'c.d': 'e'}
```

but i am not able to solve it completely .

Comment: You would have to do it recursively for each of the inner dictionaries.

Comment: What's the expected output for `{"a": {"b": 2}, "a.b": 1}`?

Comment: Depending on what you are trying to achieve, there could be other ways to do the same. As @Kevin mentioned, this could cause ambiguity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do it recursively for each dictionary.

This works.

```
>>>
>>> def handle(inp):
...     out = {}
...     for i in inp:
...         if type(inp[i]) is dict:
...             inp[i]=handle(inp[i])
...             for jj in inp[i].keys():
...                 out[i+'.'+jj] = inp[i][jj]
...         else:
...             out[i] = inp[i]
...     return out
...
>>> handle(inp)
{'a': 'b', 'c.f.i': 'j', 'c.d': 'e', 'c.f.g': 'h'}
>>>
```